# cardinality of the complement of a countable subset of R

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The excercise is to prove that for any countable set of $\mathbb{R}$ , let s call it A, its complement $\mathbb{R}/A$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. The solution I am aware of is straightforward, assuming countable choice, making a second countable subset, taking the union of those two sets, assuming a bijection and so on, but i wanted to try something diffirent, without assuming choice, and i don't know if it s correct.
My thought is that for any countable set, i can write it down as $A=\{a_0, a_1,....\}$ but not necceserily in increasing order. If it was in increasing order, i could simply say that $(a_0, a_1) \in \mathbb{R}-A$ and thus $|\mathbb{R}-A|>=\mathbb{R}$, so i have the equality. I am stuck at proving that there are $a_i, a_j \in A $ such that $a_n \notin (a_i,a_j ) $for any $a_n \in A$. The problem is that this does not hold for any choice of $a_i$. For example, if $A= \{0\} \cup \{ 1/n \}$, then obviously for $0 $ this does not hold, although it holds for any other element. Is there any easy and fast way to get past this?

Comment: There is a really easy proof if you already know that $|\mathbb R\times\mathbb R|=|\mathbb R|.$ It's based on the fact that, given any countable set $B$ of points in the plane, you can find a line in the plane which misses $B.$

Answer (score 3):

For countable (finite or infinite) $A\subset \mathbb R$ find a countably infinite $B\subset \mathbb R$ that is disjoint from $A.$ Show there is a bijection $f:B\to B\cup A.$ Extend $f$ to the domain $\mathbb R$ \ $A$ by letting $f(x)=x$ for $x\in \mathbb R \setminus (B\cup A).$ Then $f:(\mathbb R$ \ $A) \to \mathbb R$ is a bijection.

If you want, I will show how to find $B$ without the Axiom of Choice and by the most elementary methods.

Appendix. To find $B$: If $A$ is empty let $B=\mathbb N.$ If $A\ne\phi$ let $A=\{a_n:n\in \mathbb N\}.$ It does not matter whether $a_m=a_n$ for some $m\ne n.$ Let $(a_{n,j})_{j\in \mathbb N}$ be the sequence of decimal digits of $a_n$ to the right of the decimal point, in base $10,$ where $a_{n,j}\ne 9$ for infinitely many $j.$ Let $a^*_j=1$ if $a_{j,j}$ is even and let $a^*_j=2$ if $a_{j,j}$ is odd. Let $d=\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}a^*_j10^{-j}.$ Let $B=\{2\cdot 10^{-j}+d:j\in \mathbb N\}.$

Comment: Your argument can be generalized. If $A \subset X$ and you can find a subset $B$ disjoint from $A$ with a cardinality not less than $A$'s, then $X - A $ has same cardinality as $X$. +1

Comment: @MikeMathMan. Yes. It's quite easy with AC as then WLOG we need only consider subsets of an infinite cardinal ordinal. I wanted to do the Q in ZF.

Comment: Working on the exercise you left us. Do you use Cauchy sequences or real analysis? (sketching something out).

Comment: @MikeMathMan. A variation on Cantor's diagonal method of showing that $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, to show that if $A$ is countable then we can construct not just 1, but a countable infinity of members of $\mathbb R$ \ $A.$

Comment: I am interested - please add to your answer your elementary construction. I found a way, but only by using some (elementary?) real analysis.

Comment: @MikeMathMan. I have added an appendix to my A with a way to find $B$.

Answer (score 3):

Here we construct. without recourse to the axiom of choice, a countable subset $B$ that is disjoint from $A$; the OP can then use DanielWainfleet's argument, arriving at the desired solution.

Suppose for some $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $a \lt b$ the closed interval $[a,b]$ is disjoint from $A$. Then it is trivial to construct $B$. So, we assume that every interval in $\mathbb{R}$ has a nonempty intersection with $A$.

Let the set $A$ be enumerated with a sequence $a_n$.

Definition: The $a_n \text{-distance}$ of any interval $[a,b]$ is the smallest integer $n_0$ such that $a_{n_0} \in [a,b]$.

Lemma 1: A real number $\hat b$ can be recursively constructed, belonging to the open interval $(0,1)$, that is distinct from the elements in $A$.
Proof
Starting with the closed interval $[0,1]$, divide it into 5 equal pieces and examine the two 'snug'intervals $[\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5}]$ and $[\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5}]$, selecting the one with the larger $a_n \text{-distance}$. Repeat this process.

This process gives us a nested sequence of closed intervals. By basic properties of the real numbers, the intersection of this decreasing chain of intervals is a singleton $\{\hat b\}$. But it also easy to see that each new nested interval must have a larger $a_n \text{-distance}$ than the preceding one. This of course means that the $\{\hat b\} \cap A = \emptyset$. $\qquad \blacksquare$

Proposition 2: A countable set $B$ can be constructed such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.
Proof
Note that $A$ is a subset of a larger countable set $A^{`}$, the 'integer translate set $A + \mathbb{Z}$. If a real number $b$ is not in $A^{`}$, then $b + m \notin A^{`}$ for any integer $m$. So, apply lemma 1 to 
$A^{`}$ getting the number $\hat b$. Next, collect the translations $\hat b + m$ to form a countable set disjoint from $A$.

Note that we have also shown that there is no bijective mapping between a countable set $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Nicely done..............

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an infinite countable set, thus $A=\{a_1,a_3...a_n....\}$

Take a countable set $B=\{b_1,b_2...\}$ such that $B \cap A =\emptyset$

Clearly $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A$ is uncountable.

Take an enumeration of $A\cup B$

such that $A \cup B=\{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2....a_n,b_n...\}$

Take $f: (\mathbb{R}-A) \to \mathbb{R}$
where

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\
           x &x \in \mathbb{R}-(A \cup B)\\
           a_{n} & x=b_{2n-1}\\
           b_{n} &x=b_{2n}\\
             \end{cases}$

$\text{$f$ is bijective } \Rightarrow |\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}-A|$

Comment: The definition of f requires A to be infinite.   Yes, f is injective into  R - {a_1}, but not into R - A.  So how can you claim card R <= card (R - A)?

Comment: Because a_0 is mapped to a_1 which is not in R - A.

Comment: @WilliamElliot indeed my answer was wrong...sorry for doubting you and for the confusion...I edited an attempt to  fix it..hope now it is corect.

Comment: How do you construct B without a countable axiom of choice?

Comment: @WilliamElliot..i did not see that in the post..careless from my part..Now i thought that we can take an injective but not surjective $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$..for instance $ e^x$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}-f(\mathbb{R})$..Then  i can define the  sequence $a_n=f^n(x_0)$ where $a_0=x_0$ where $f^n$ is the composition $n$-times..Now i'm not sure if this is uses choice

Comment: So $B$ can be the set of the elements of the sequence

Comment: And also we must construct $B$ such that does not intersect $A$

Comment: Show A + A is countable and pick a point p, not in A + A.  Is p + A the set you want?

Comment: @WilliamElliot thanks for the suggestion..i will keep it in mind ..i will try to constract a set with the above way first and then if i do not manage then i will  use your hint

Answer (score 0):

Let A = { a1, a2,.. aj,.. } be a countable subset of the reals R.
B = { a - b | a,b in A } is countable.  Thus some p in R - B.
p + A is countable and disjoint from A.  Otherwise
some a,b in A with p + a = b, p = b - a in B, a contradiction.

Define f:R -> R - A by
f(x) = x, if x not in A $\cup$ p+A
f(a_j) = p + a_2j, for all a_j in A
f(p + a_j) = p + a_(2j-1), for all p + a_j in p + A
f is a bijection;  R and R - A are equinumerous.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof that uses the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to
$\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. the set of functions $\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$. So let $A\subseteq \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a countable subset and consider an enumeration $A=\{f_{0},f_{1},f_{2},\dots\}$ of $A$. It is enough to find an
injection from $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\setminus A$.
So let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ a function. We define $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{N}\to
\{0,1\}$ as follows:

$$\tilde{f}(n)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 1-f_{k}(n), & n=2k \ \ \text{for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$} \\
f(k), & n=2k+1 \ \ \text{for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$}. \end{matrix}\right. $$

Then, the function $\Phi:f\mapsto \tilde{f}$ is the desired function. The definition of $\tilde{f}$ on $2\mathbb{N}$ implies that $\tilde{f}\not\in A$, while the
definition of it on $2\mathbb{N}+1$ implies that $\Phi$ is an injection.